# Статические переменные в Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c

В objective-c мне необходимо создать такие переменные, которые похожи на статические переменные в java.

Да, в objective-c тоже есть статические переменные, но чтобы ими пользоваться, необходимо импортировать файл, в котором они описаны. А, это сводит их использование на нет. Так как я хочу присвоить им значение в одном классе, и  использовать это значение в другом - при таком использовании они теряют свои значение. Чем хороши статические переменные в java: я создаю статический класс `AllMasssives` и в нем описываю статическую переменную products. Далее в другом классе я просто пишу `AllMassives.products = 5`, и в следующем классе знаю значение `AllMassives.products` и оно равно 5.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этим! 
Т.е мне необходимо некое такое хранилище в objective-c, с помощью которого я могу обмениваться данными. В java очень хорошо помогали статические переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// TheClass.h
@interface TheClass : NSObject
+ (int)count;
@end

// TheClass.m
static int theCount = 0;

@implementation TheClass
+ (int) count { return theCount; }
@end
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо!))